# Как отправить картинку на печать?

Tags: c#, print

Как отправить картинку на печать?

Comment: @cas-live а что вам на это ответил Гугл?

Comment: @DreamChild, Очень много всего, но я уже сам разобрался

Comment: @cas-live тогда лучше опубликуйте ответ, может, кому-то пригодится

Comment: @DreamChild, Хорошо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void print()
    {
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument Document = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        Document.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(Document_PrintPage);
            DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Document.Print();
            }
        }
        void Document_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(form.homeDir + "basa/waybill/waybill_" + form.n_zakaz + ".png"), new Point(0, 0)); //Картинка на печать
        }
```